# React Native modal that can render custom Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have beed searching for a while to find a react native modal, popup, or even an alert that can actually render a custom component, rather than simple text.
What i actually want to do is throw a modal with a 5-star rating component, but neither of the packages i have added support that.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution which you can put anything inside View:

```
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

<Modal isVisible={this.state.alertState} onBackButtonPress={()=>this.setState({alertState:false})} >
  <View style={styles.modal}>
    <Text style={styles.modalText}>modal Text!</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.setState({alertState:false})} style={styles.modalButton}>
        <Text style={styles.modalButtonText}>Ok!</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

and here is style:

```
modal:{
backgroundColor:'white',height:.2*DEVICE_HEIGHT,alignItems:'center',width:.9*DEVICE_WIDTH,justifyContent:'center',borderRadius:10},

modalText:{
fontFamily:'IRANYekanMobileFN',padding:10},
modalButton:{
backgroundColor:'#306BF4',width:.25*DEVICE_WIDTH,height:.05*DEVICE_HEIGHT,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',marginTop:20,borderRadius:10},
modalButtonText:{
fontFamily:'IRANYekanMobileFN',color:'white'}
```